# How can I add the mathematical symbol for 'power' (like X ^ 2) to a question?

Tags: support, markdown

I'm asking a simple question on Stack Overflow. The question is somehow related to mathematics. Is there a way to show the mathematical symbol for power (X^Y) appropriately?

Edit: The following question [What HTML tags are allowed on Stack Exchange sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1777/162704) provides a complete reference.

Comment: Are you talking about a MathJax approach? Then you would use `$x^y$` on sites that support it (like [math.se]).

Comment: Related: [What HTML tags are allowed on Stack Exchange sites?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1777/162704)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

On the sites that don't support MathJax, you can use `<sup>`.

```
x<sup>2</sup>
```

will produce: x<sup>2</sup>

Comment: Does it work in a comment? x<sup>2</sup> 
How about inline code `x<sup>2</sup>`

Comment: It doesn't.. and I would love to have some nice syntax for writing mathematical symbols in comments.. any chance of it?

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri unicode magic, e.g. x²

Comment: @ShadowWizardWearingMask how do you write U+00B2 like symbol here? but I need to write codes then.. which is not comfortable.

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri no, just copy and paste. You can copy from my comment, or from [such a page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superscripts_and_Subscripts_(Unicode_block)) that lists more.

Comment: @ShadowWizardWearingMask that's not serious. :)

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri why not? It's a workaround. I find it easy to use, in the few cases I'll need it.

Answer (score 7):

Another way is to use Unicode characters, e.g. ['SUPERSCRIPT TWO' (U+00B2)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/b2/index.htm):
X²

The downside is the possible lack of support in some operating systems.

The upside is simplicity, and it also works in chat and comments, where Markdown support is very basic.

For more details, see *[Superscripts and Subscripts (Unicode block)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superscripts_and_Subscripts_(Unicode_block))*.

Comment: More serious downsides are a very limited character repertoir available, and impossibility of nesting the superscripts.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek well this is just for the basic usage, but yes I agree it's not very ideal.

Comment: A more complete list is given in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts .